# Assign last value of if else statement to variable

Tags: c++

I know that you can assign a variable like this:

```
double y = 140;
int i = (y > 100) ? y / 2 : y * 2; //shorthand if else
std::cout << i << std::endl;  // 70
```

Or for multiple commands seperated with a `,`:

```
double y = 140;
int i = (y > 100) ? (y /= 2, 5) : (y *= 2, 10);
std::cout << i << std::endl; // 5
std::cout << y << std::endl; // 70
```

But can I do this with a normal if else statement?

I tried this:

```
int i = if(y > 100){
            y / 2;
        } else {
            y * 2;
        }
```

Or with the whole if statement in `{ if..}` brackets but that doesn't work.

Is it possible to do it with a normal if else statement in which the last expression the value is which assign to the variable (without a method, function or lambda)?

Comment: This is only possible with a immediately invoked lambda, if you don't want to declare the variable beforehand.

Comment: In C++ `if` is a *statement*, not an *expression*, hence your last example won't compile

Comment: i find it confusing that your second code snippet is doing something else. The third is supposed to result in the same as the first or as the second

Comment: @All Thanks for your help and answers! So I learned something new :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible within your limitations. For the record, the lambda solution looks like this:

```
int i = [&]{
    if(y > 100) {
        return y / 2;
    } else {
        return y * 2;
    }
}();
```

Comment: `return …; } else` 

Comment: An IIFE, yay! :)

Comment: @Biffen I went for minimal modification. Of course reflowing the code is left as an excercise to the reader :p

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. An `if` does not return anything, it's a flow control statement. If you want to do it, you'd have to do it "manually":

```
int i;

if(y > 100){
        y /= 2;
        i = 5; 
    } else {
        y *= 2;
        i = 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this way:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double y = 140;
    int i;
if(y > 100){
        y =y/2;
        i = 5; 
    } else {
        y =y*2;
        i = 10;
    }
    cout<<i<<endl;
    cout<<y<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The below code snippent won't work because `if` does not return anything, it's just a statement.

```
 int i = if(y > 100){
                y / 2;
            } else {
                y * 2;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you littering perfectly good code with `using namespace std;`... Stop. Get some help.